# How do I read two folders in a directory and combine them under one label using flow_from_directory?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, directory, conv-neural-network

Tensorflow/Keras

I want to classify images into either "Circle", "Square" or "Triangle". I have a directory containing 6 folders with each shape having a separate "shaded" or "unshaded" folder. How can I combine them into one category? For example: shaded and unshaded circles will be given a label "0" using flow_from_directory. I will then feed this into my CNN model and let it run.

Thanks for the help!

Comment: It would be good if you explained that you are using tensorflow/keras in both the header and tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`classes` in `flow_from_directory` needs to match the subdirectory names.

**Example:**

```sh
shapes
├── circle
│   ├── shared
│   └── unshared
├── square
│   ├── shared
│   └── unshared
└── triangle
    ├── shared
    └── unshared
```

```py
import pathlib
# Get project root depending on your project structure.
PROJECT_ROOT = pathlib.Path().cwd().parent
SHAPES = PROJECT_ROOT / "shapes"

train_gen = ImageDataGenerator(
).flow_from_directory(
    directory=SHAPES, # the path to the 'shapes' directory.
    target_size=(IMAGE_WIDTH, IMAGE_HEIGHT),
    classes=["circle", "square", "triangle"],
    batch_size=8,
    class_mode="categorical",
)
```

**Output:**

```sh
Found 12 images belonging to 3 classes.
```

Comment: This works! I think I see my mistake. I had a shape folder in another shape folder, so directory could not locate the folder. I will try to build my model now.

Comment: Great! Glad it helped! If you are satisfied, please consider marking the answers as solved :)